# StackBlitz - Property entries does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Tags: ecmascript-6, stackblitz

I am trying to use this syntax in StackBlitz:

```
const someObject = {};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(someObject)) {
   // .... do whatever
}
```

The editor is underlining the `entries` in red and stating that "Property entries does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'".

However the code is still working. It seems to just be a linting issue where the editor thinks this won't work... but it does.

here is the stackblitz if someone could help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validation-errors

How can I get the editor to know the language properly?

Comment: Please fix link

Comment: apologies. fixed now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out that Stackblitz doesn't know which version of TypeScript you are using. By default babel targets to specification es5, but as I know `Object.entries` was added in es2017.

To fix your problem simply add this in your DEPENDENCIES section in input called **enter package name**

```
npm i typescript
```

or

```
typescript
```

I've checked that and I'm getting now perfect working intellisense

Comment: Working fine. (Y)